# Pexpect script gives "None" for output

Tags: python, pexpect

The below script prints `None` when ran on the server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
import sys
dcommand = ('ls')
child = pexpect.spawn(dcommand)
output = child.before
print output
```

Not sure why this is - here is a comparison of what happens when i run ls manually - there's definitely stuff there!

```
[root@dub-svrfarm27 ~]# python script.py
None
[root@dub-svrfarm27 ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg  auto_ovirt_st_setup.py  install_time  kickstart-post.log  original-ks.cfg  script.py
```

Any ideas? I'm sure its something silly, but what...

Comment: Python 2 has reached end of life, you should upgrade to Python 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to expect the `prompt` and then read the data from the buffer for each operation like,

```
(pilenv) bash-5.0$ cat ll.py 
import pexpect
import sys
dcommand = 'ls'
child = pexpect.spawn(dcommand)
child.expect(r'.*$') # my prompt ends with $, if yours ends with something else, then use that
print(child.readline()) 

(pilenv) bash-5.0$ python ll.py 
b'agust.py\t     IMG-20191213-WA0000.jpg  lib    l.py\r\n'
(pilenv) bash-5.0$
```

Also please refer the [code](https://github.com/millefalcon/pssh/blob/master/pssh/pssh.py) for a sane way to use `pexpect` which i did for something personal :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
import sys
dcommand = ('ls')
child = pexpect.spawn(dcommand)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
output = child.before
print(output)
```

you need to add child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
you can find more information at https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html